# IP summarization

Tags: security, networking, ip

How can I summarization these IPs

10.255.210.12

10.255.210.48

10.255.210.100

10.255.210.112

10.255.210.124

10.255.210.136

10.255.210.140

10.255.210.172

And this:

10.255.211.4

10.255.211.132

10.255.211.168

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You won't be able to summarize them unless they are sequential.

For example, let's say you have a few network prefixes:

10.1.1.1 and 10.1.1.2 for a peer to peer link
10.5.4.0/24 for a user network and 10.5.5.0/24 for their VoIP phones.

10.1.1.1 and 10.1.1.2 can be aggregated as 10.1.1.0/30, 10.1.1.0 being the network address and 10.1.1.3 as the broadcast.

The second set could be summarized as 10.5.4.0/23, 10.5.5.255 being broadcast.

If they are not in sequence and not in increments of 2 (2,4,8,16,32,etc), then you will be limited.